# inverse elements except for zero in a numpy vector

Tags: python, numpy

In python, I'm trying to inverse a numpy vector except for these elements with zero values.

- I used vectorize function, but always got a wrong answer when the first element is zero, (the code works well when zeros are not in the first position ).

```
active_N=np.array([0,1,3,5])
f=np.vectorize(lambda x:x if x==0 else 1./x)
active_N_inverse=f(active_N)
```

Run the code then I get

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0])
```

What was wrong with the codes above?
Is there any other method to solve this problem with high efficiency?

Comment: I think you meant to do `f(active_N)`

Comment: Instead of vectorizing a function, you might consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70014001/make-elements-with-value-division-by-zero-equal-to-zero-in-a-2d-numpy-array

Comment: yeah I made a typo, it should be f(active_N)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`np.divide`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.divide.html) with a `where` clause:

```
np.divide(1, active_N, where=active_N!=0)
```

Optionally combined with `round`:

```
np.divide(1, active_N, where=active_N!=0).round(100)
```

Output:

```
array([0.        , 1.        , 0.33333333, 0.2       ])
```